# SQL Query giving inconsistant results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table which logs chat messages

```
CREATE TABLE message_log
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  message text,
  from_id character varying(500),
  to_id character varying(500),
  match_id character varying(500),
  unix_timestamp bigint,
  own_account boolean,
  reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT message_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

A chat conversation will have the same `match_id`

I want a query that would return a list of match_ids which the last message related to the `match_id` (the last message of the chat conversation) is from the non account holder (`own_account = false`)

I came up with the following query, but it is giving inconsistent results which I don't understand.

```
select * from message_log
where from_id <> ?
  and to_id = ?
  and  unix_timestamp in ( select distinct max(unix_timestamp)
                           from message_log group by match_id )
```

The question mark in the SQL query represents the account holder's user id

Comment: what does inconsistent mean?

Comment: It's working as thought for some chat conversations and returning some chat_ids which the last message is from the account holder. So it's not working correctly. Does my query look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you need to bind the `message_id` back to the base query as well, otherwise you could be getting a unix_timestamp from a different message:

```
select m.*
  from message_log m
  where m.from_id <> ?
    and m.to_id = ?
    and m.unix_timestamp = ( select max(unix_timestamp)
                               from message_log
                               where match_id = m.match_id
                               group by match_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `distinct on`.  This is specific to Postgres, but designed for this situation:

```
select distinct on (match_id) ml.*
from message_log ml
where from_id <> ? and to_id = ?
order by match_id, unix_timestamp desc;
```